# QDate conversions from/to string inconsistent (issue with the century)

Tags: c++, qt, date

Looks like a wrong feature in Qt (to avoid to call it a bug).

Code:

```
   QDate qdate(2020,12,05);
   QString qstring = QLocale::system().toString(qdate, QLocale::ShortFormat);

   QDate qdate2 = QDate::fromString(qstring, QLocale::system().dateFormat(QLocale::ShortFormat));
   QString qstring2 = QLocale::system().toString(qdate, QLocale::ShortFormat);

    #define __DV(x) qDebug() << #x " =" << x

   __DV(qdate);
   __DV(qstring);
   __DV(qdate2);
   __DV(qstring2);
```

Output:

```
qdate = QDate("2020-12-05")
qstring = "05-12-20"
qdate2 = QDate("1920-12-05")
qstring2 = "05-12-20"
```

So, in the above code, I do not encode date strings myself, I'm just letting Qt to generate strings using QLocale::ShortFormat and interpreting its own result back to QDate, still using QLocale::ShortFormat.  And Qt is mishandling the century.

Please note that I only need to work in the 21st century here. That's Qt that transform it in 20th century's date

The long format is too much for me but mm-dd-yyyy would be OK. I need to keep using QLocale. I need to save the date in a text file(i.e. as a string), and later read it back.  Also I need to show it the shortest possible way in a QTableWidget.

The problem is that Qdate string formatting in connection to QLocale is not very flexible, and Qt doesn't have a consistent interpretation in both direction of the QDate to/from QString conversions.

Of course, I may for sure solve this the long way (in terms of coding and runtime), but I wonder if there something that I'm doing wrong and that could be solved easily and a more clean way?

Comment: Which part do you think is incorrect: Converting from string to QDate or QDate to string?

Comment: None taken separately is really wrong. But together, they should be consistent: either both use implicitly the 20th century, or the 21st. But, IMHO, definitely not one the 20th, and the other the 21st.  I would also tend to say that the short format should keep the year in 4 digits to avoid trouble.  It they really want a two digits century, they could keep it in the existing NarrowFormat, or create a VeryShortFormat or so.

Comment: Also I would tend to say that a two digits year should mean the current century but that's a matter of taste.

Comment: This is indeed a bug, cf. https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-89147